# How to pass variable values in this for loop in shell script

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script, where I am trying to expand one variable in `for loop`. I google for that but did not find any solution. However this question is very similar to my question but not getting the solution.

[expanding variables in shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572334/expanding-variables-in-shell-script)

Please check this

```
time_stamp_1=$(date --date="1min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_2=$(date --date="2min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_3=$(date --date="3min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_4=$(date --date="4min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_5=$(date --date="5min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_6=$(date --date="6min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_7=$(date --date="7min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_8=$(date --date="8min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_9=$(date --date="9min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_10=$(date --date="10min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_11=$(date --date="11min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_12=$(date --date="12min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_13=$(date --date="13min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_14=$(date --date="14min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")
time_stamp_15=$(date --date="15min ago" +"%a %b %e %H:%M")

for i in {1..15}
do
    req=`$time_stamp_${i}`
    echo "req = $req"
done
```

How can I print `time_stamp` 1 to 15 values???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in {1..15}
do
  set time_stamp_$i
  echo req = ${!1}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in {1..15}
do
    req=$(echo \$time_stamp_$i)
    eval echo "req = $req"
done
```